# SQL Error: 17401, SQLState: 99999 Protocol violation: [6, 7, 0]

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, oracle10g, ojdbc

Looking for help with an intermittent error.  Following extract is from the log file.  Can't think what else to add but I will add more if needed.

```
    13 Oct 2015 14:37:43,691 2746599 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  snbts.proteus.integrationengine.IntegrationThread  - Processing batch: 16888445 on integration Queue 1
13 Oct 2015 14:37:46,831 2749739 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  snbts.proteus.integrationengine.IntegrationThread  - Queue 2 is alive.
13 Oct 2015 14:37:52,706 2755614 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 17401, SQLState: 99999
13 Oct 2015 14:37:52,706 2755614 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Protocol violation: [6, 7, 0]
13 Oct 2015 14:37:52,706 2755614 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener  - Error performing load command
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [snbts.proteus.dataaccess.IntegrationQueue#2]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1799)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:862)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:820)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.intercept(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:158)
    at snbts.proteus.dataaccess.IntegrationQueue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$14c8fbf7.setStatus(<generated>)
    at snbts.proteus.integrationengine.IntegrationThread.setStatus(IntegrationThread.java:109)
    at snbts.proteus.integrationengine.IntegrationThread.run(IntegrationThread.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [6, 7, 0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:464)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1669)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1785)
    ... 24 more
13 Oct 2015 14:37:52,706 2755614 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR snbts.proteus.integrationengine.IntegrationThread  - Problem updating database: could not load an entity: [snbts.proteus.dataaccess.IntegrationQueue#2]
13 Oct 2015 14:37:54,752 2757660 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection  - [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
13 Oct 2015 14:37:54,752 2757660 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection  - [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation ] which will not be reported to listeners!
java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIiov.unmarshalV10(T4CTTIiov.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readIOV(T4C8Oall.java:592)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:325)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1669)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1785)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:862)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:820)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.intercept(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:158)
    at snbts.proteus.dataaccess.IntegrationQueue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$14c8fbf7.toString(<generated>)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printString(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at snbts.proteus.integrationengine.queue.QueueItem.build(QueueItem.java:72)
    at snbts.proteus.integrationengine.IntegrationThread.processIntegrationQueue(IntegrationThread.java:58)
    at snbts.proteus.integrationengine.IntegrationThread.run(IntegrationThread.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Versions we are using:

- Java 6
- Hibernate 3.1.3
- ojdbc6 11.2.0.4.0
- Oracle 10g EE 10.2.0.5.0 64bit

Method attempting to load the entity:

```
    private boolean setStatus(final String status) {

    LOGGER.trace(String.format("Setting status to: %s on %s", status, integrationQueue.getDescription()));

    boolean hasDbConnection = true;

    try {
        final Session session = CustomSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        LOGGER.trace(CustomSessionFactory.TRANSACTION_BEGUN);

        this.integrationQueue = (IntegrationQueue)session.load(IntegrationQueue.class, integrationQueue.getId());
        integrationQueue.setStatus(status);
        session.update(integrationQueue);
        session.flush();
        LOGGER.trace(String.format("Session Object Update: Integration Queue %d", integrationQueue.getId()));

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        LOGGER.trace(CustomSessionFactory.TRANSACTION_COMMITTED);

        LOGGER.trace(String.format("Status set to: %s on %s", status, integrationQueue.getDescription()));
    } catch (org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("Database Connection Problem: %s", e.getMessage()));
        CustomSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().removeSession();
        hasDbConnection = false;
    } catch (GenericJDBCException e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("Problem updating database: %s", e.getMessage()));
    }

    return hasDbConnection;
```

Entity:

```
public class IntegrationQueue implements Serializable {

public static final String STATUS_SHUTDOWN = "Shutdown";
public static final String STATUS_ACTIVE = "Active";
public static final String STATUS_IDLE = "Idle";
public static final String STATUS_ERROR_WC = "Error - Wrong Configuration";


private long id;
private String description;
private String status;
private IntegrationEngine integrationEngine;

public IntegrationQueue() {
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(final String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public IntegrationEngine getIntegrationEngine() {
    return integrationEngine;
}

public void setIntegrationEngine(final IntegrationEngine integrationEngine) {
    this.integrationEngine = integrationEngine;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(final String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("Integration Queue: %d - %s", id, status);
}
```

}

HBM File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="snbts.proteus.dataaccess.IntegrationQueue" table="INTEGRATIONQUEUE">

        <id name="id" type="long" column="INTEGRATIONQUEUE_ID">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>

        <property name="description" type="string" column="DESCRIPTION">
            <meta attribute="field-description">
                The description of the record.
            </meta>
        </property>

        <property name="status" type="string" column="STATUS">
            <meta attribute="field-description">
                The status of the record.
            </meta>
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="integrationEngine" class="snbts.proteus.dataaccess.IntegrationEngine"
                     column="INTEGRATIONENGINE_ID" not-null="true"/>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: You need to show us your code. The exception alone isn't enough to tell where the problem is.

Comment: I have added code, thanks

Comment: @DANNY1000000 Did you solve you problem ? I've nearly the same error

Comment: @GillesBodart I updated the driver and, if I recall correctly, there may have been a session that remained open somewhere in my code.  After closing the session and updating the driver I havent seen the issue again.